# Keyboard entry using Office Equations Editor

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, equation-editor

Does anyone know where to find instructions on how to enter equations into the 2007/2010 equation editors using only the keyboard? Googling just gives many links to people talking about how great the editor is, not instructions on how to use it. I have seen this shown in multiple demos of the product, but there are no instructions for it anywhere, even in the MS help.

Answer (score 2):

This [page](http://ist.uwaterloo.ca/ec/equations/equation2007.html) has a tutorial and some examples for the Word 2007 editor.

You can also learn (well reverse engineer) the language by entering an equation in the graphical editor, then switching it to linear form to see how to build it up.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion of looking at the linear form

Comment: Also, you might note that the editor will automatically convert the equation as you go: typing `\pi r`^2 will turn into to _πr²_ as soon as you've typed a space at the end or done something similar to tell the editor you're done typing.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a description of the "language" used in the equation editor along with examples in [this pdf](http://www.unicode.org/notes/tn28/UTN28-PlainTextMath-v2.pdf).